# Join streaming based on key - Spark/Kafka

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

Suppose 2 streaming given by spark and one of streaming is not 100 % in sync. There might be difference in getting streaming. We need to join streaming by key. Is there any way we can do it without any persistent ?

Comment: what do you mean by not 100% in sync, do you mean they have delays in between them?

Comment: by persistent do you mean storing in a state store ?

Comment: @marvel308 yes. It may be delay for few seconds and persistent mean stored in some external storage or without caching

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible, Kafka Streams ships with built-in support to interpret the data in a Kafka topic as such a continuously updated table.  In the Kafka Streams DSL this is achieved via the so-called [Ktable](http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/concepts.html#ktable)

these KTables are backed by [state stores](http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/architecture.html#state) in Kafka Streams.  These state stores are local to your application (more precisely: they are local to the instances of your application, of which there can be one or many), which means that interacting with these state stores does not require talking over the network, so read and write operations are very fast. Incase you decided not to persist data, you might start losing information which you might not want